# Why i my utterance does not trigger the intent?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

when i say get me in the end, it would not trigger that intent that i intent to trigger.

/* *

- This sample demonstrates handling intents from an Alexa skill using the Alexa Skills Kit SDK (v2).
- Please visit https://alexa.design/cookbook for additional examples on implementing slots, dialog management,
- session persistence, api calls, and more.
- */

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const msg = require("./localisation");
const constants = require("./constants");

const getSlotValues = (handlerInput) => {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots;
}

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = msg.HELLO_MSG;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
//If user the say follow up, we are going to ask another question.
const FollowUpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'FollowUpIntentHandler';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const {responseBuilder, attributesManager} = handlerInput;
        const slotValue = getSlotValues(handlerInput);
        const sessionAttribute = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        sessionAttribute['follow']= slotValue.follow.value;
        // const sessionAttribute = attributeManager.getSessionAttributes();
        // const slotValues = getSlotValues(handlerInput);

        // sessionAttribute["follow"] = slotValues.follow.value;

        const speakOutput = msg.FOLLOW_UP_QUESTION_MSG;
        return responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
//If user the say new we are going to ask another question.
const NewIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput){
        const {request} = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;
        return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && request.intent.name === "NewIntentHandler";
    },
    handle(handlerInput){
        const {responseBuilder, attributeManager} = handlerInput;
        const sessionAttribute = attributeManager.getSessionAttributes();
        const slotValues = getSlotValues(handlerInput);

        sessionAttribute["new"] = slotValues.new.value;
        
        const speakOutput = msg.NEW_QUESTION_MSG;
     
        return responseBuilder.speak(speakOutput).reprompt(speakOutput).getResponse();

    }   
};
const CaptureUserQuestionIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput){
        const {request} = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;
        const {attributesManager} = handlerInput;
        const sessionAttribute = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

        return request.type === "IntentRequest"
            && request.intent.name === "CaptureUserQuestionIntentHandler"
            || sessionAttribute['new']
            || sessionAttribute['follow'];
    },
    handle(handlerInput){
       const slotValue = getSlotValues(handlerInput);
       const {responseBuilder, attributesManager} = handlerInput;
       const sessionAttribute = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
       
       sessionAttribute["bodyPart"] = slotValue.bodyPart.value;
       sessionAttribute["drainage"] = slotValue.drainage.value;
       sessionAttribute["time"] = slotValue.time.value;
       
    //   const bodyPart = slotValue.bodyPart.value;
    //   const time = slotValue.time.value;
    //   const drainage = slotValue.drainage.value;

       const speakOutput = `What is the ${sessionAttribute['drainage']} coming from? The back of the ear near the incision or the opening of your ear or ear canal?`;
       
       return responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse()

    }
};

const BackOrNearIncisionIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput){
        const {request} = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;
        const {attributesManager} =  handlerInput;
        const sessionAttribute = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        
        return request.type === "IntentRequest"
            && request.intent.name === "BackOrNearIncisionIntentHandler"
            && sessionAttribute["drainage"];
    },
    handle(handlerInput){
        const slotValues = getSlotValues(handlerInput);
        const {attributesManager, responseBuilder} = handlerInput;
        const sessionAttribute = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        
        let speakOutput;
        
        sessionAttribute['color'] = slotValues.color.value;
        const color = sessionAttribute['color'];
        
        if(color === constants.CLEAR){
            speakOutput = msg.IMPORANT_GET_TREATED; 
        }else{
             speakOutput = msg.SUGGEST_APPLY_MEDICINE;
        }
       
        return responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse()
        
    }
};

const YesPleaseIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput){
        const {request} = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;
        const {attributesManager} = handlerInput;
        const sessionAttribute = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        
        
        return request.type === "IntentRequest"
            && request.intent.name === "AMAZON.YesIntent"
            && sessionAttribute["color"] === constants.CLEAR;
    },
    handle(handlerInput){
        const {responseBuilder} = handlerInput;
        // let speakOutput = msg.YOUR_NEXT_APPOINTMENT;
        let speakOutput = msg.YOUR_NEXT_APPOINTMENT;
        
        return responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse()
    }
};

const UserIntentHandlers = {
    canHandle(handlerInput){
        const {request} = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;
      
        
        return request.type === "IntentRequest"
            && request.intent.name === "UserIntentHandler";
    },
    handle(handlerInput){
        const {responseBuilder} = handlerInput;
        // let speakOutput = msg.YOUR_NEXT_APPOINTMENT;
        let speakOutput = msg.YOUR_NEXT_APPOINTMENT;
        console.log(responseBuilder);
        return responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse()
    }
};

const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'You can say hello to me! How can I help?';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && (Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
                || Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Goodbye!';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
/* *
 * FallbackIntent triggers when a customer says something that doesn’t map to any intents in your skill
 * It must also be defined in the language model (if the locale supports it)
 * This handler can be safely added but will be ingnored in locales that do not support it yet 
 * */
const FallbackIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.FallbackIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Sorry, I don\'t know about that. Please try again.';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
/* *
 * SessionEndedRequest notifies that a session was ended. This handler will be triggered when a currently open 
 * session is closed for one of the following reasons: 1) The user says "exit" or "quit". 2) The user does not 
 * respond or says something that does not match an intent defined in your voice model. 3) An error occurs 
 * */
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        console.log(`~~~~ Session ended: ${JSON.stringify(handlerInput.requestEnvelope)}`);
        // Any cleanup logic goes here.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse(); // notice we send an empty response
    }
};
/* *
 * The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
 * It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers for your intents 
 * by defining them above, then also adding them to the request handler chain below 
 * */
const IntentReflectorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const intentName = Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope);
        const speakOutput = `You just triggered ${intentName}`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
/**
 * Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
 * stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
 * the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below 
 * */
const ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle() {
        return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput, error) {
        const speakOutput = 'Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again.';
        console.log(`~~~~ Error handled: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

/**
 * This handler acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
 * payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
 * defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom 
 * */
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        YesPleaseIntentHandler,
        FollowUpIntentHandler,
        BackOrNearIncisionIntentHandler,
        NewIntentHandler,
        CaptureUserQuestionIntentHandler,
        UserIntentHandlers,
      
        
        
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        FallbackIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        IntentReflectorHandler)
    .addErrorHandlers(
        ErrorHandler)
    .withCustomUserAgent('sample/hello-world/v1.2')
    .lambda();
```

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "lee healthcare",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "FollowUpIntentHandler",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "follow",
                            "type": "FOLLOW"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "{follow} up question",
                        "{follow} up",
                        "{follow}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "NewIntentHandler",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "new",
                            "type": "NEW"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "{new} question",
                        "{new}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "CaptureUserQuestionIntentHandler",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "bodyPart",
                            "type": "BODYPARTS"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "time",
                            "type": "customDate",
                            "samples": [
                                "{time}"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "drainage",
                            "type": "DRAIN",
                            "samples": [
                                "{drainage}"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "I have {bodyPart} surgery {time} and have {drainage}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "BackOrNearIncisionIntentHandler",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "color",
                            "type": "AMAZON.Color",
                            "samples": [
                                "{color}"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "{color}",
                        "near the incision",
                        "back of the ear near the incision"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.YesIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserIntentHandler",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "get me"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                {
                    "name": "FOLLOW",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "follow"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "NEW",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "new"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "BODYPARTS",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "ear"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "DRAIN",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "drainage"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "customDate",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "last week"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.Color",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "clear"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "dialog": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "CaptureUserQuestionIntentHandler",
                    "confirmationRequired": false,
                    "prompts": {},
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "bodyPart",
                            "type": "BODYPARTS",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": false,
                            "prompts": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "time",
                            "type": "customDate",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.832794320406.761354353518"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "drainage",
                            "type": "DRAIN",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.832794320406.873931110175"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "BackOrNearIncisionIntentHandler",
                    "confirmationRequired": false,
                    "prompts": {},
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "color",
                            "type": "AMAZON.Color",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.414884367204.126479337664"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
        },
        "prompts": [
            {
                "id": "Slot.Validation.544061479456.1369268390684.618525999294",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Can i help you with the follow question or new question?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.832794320406.761354353518",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "When does it happen?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.832794320406.873931110175",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "What else do you have ?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.414884367204.126479337664",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "What color is drainage?"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this problem?  When I created a new skill using your code and interaction model, "get me" successfully triggered the UserIntentHandlers. What intent is getting triggered?

In the Alexa Developer Console, in the "Build" tab for your skill, click "Intents" in the side menu. You'll see an "Evaluate Model" button near the top right. Click it and choose "Utterance Profiler". You can see what intent gets triggered when you say "get me".